# Connecting to google datastore from java application

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I want to connect to google datastore from normal java application not GAE app, then create entity, put/get properties and build GQL query.
 Is this possible??
I found [APIs](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) but I don't find any sample code explains how I can connect and make the authorization to the datastore.
Is it similar to [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/storage-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/storage/cmdline/StorageSample.java?repo=samples) for GCS??

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

There are examples in the [getting started guide for Cloud Datastore](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/).

Comment: The example looks right for the question, I think this answer should highlight that its getOptionsfromEnv() method depends on the exported DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT and DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE environment variables. About the second question, the GCS StorageSample uses GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder which relies on GoogleClientSecrets loaded from a /client_secrets.json, so that software is rather different.